# Trying to understand nesting IF formulas

Tags: excel-formula

In an earlier question I asked about returning the month number when the date column is formatted MM/DD/YYYY. A stack overflow member(Macro Man) provided the answer    `=MONTH(B1)`, and it worked as expected.

I learned that it also returned the number 1, when the cell was blank. This will cause a problem going into January. I found an IF formula that returns a 0 if B1 is blank:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(B91),B91,0)
```

What I am trying to do is that if B1 is blank, then the answer is zero, if B1 is not blank then it returns the number for that month. Here is the formula that I have started with:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B91),B91,0,MONTH(B90))
```

When I test the formula I get this message "You've entered too many arguments for this function."

**Could you explain what I am doing wrong & how to correct to error?**

Comment: IF accepts 3 parameters: IF (boolean, if true do this, if false do this). you put 4 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF formula is made up of 3 parts

- Logical
- True result
- False result (optional)

  =IF(Logical,True Result, False Result)

You have entered more results than the IF can handle.

So in order to reduce the number of arguments (results) for the IF formula to deal with we make your formula look like:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B91),MONTH(B91),0)
```

As an alternate to your ISNUMBER and to shorten up your formula, you could test if it is blank or "" instead and your formula would look like this:

```
IF(B91="",0,MONTH(B91))
```

Also if you do not want to display 0 and would prefer a blank cell you could adjust the above to:

```
=IF(B91="","",MONTH(B91))
```

The is number approach is a better approach if you are anticipating some other form of text.

Comment: It worked as expected. I used the middle formula. Also thank you for taking time to explain if formulas.